# Where to start with TCP communications?

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm getting ready to attempt my first project involving networked communications.  This is just a tinker-toy app with the purpose of self-teaching - nothing mission-critical here.  I will need two nodes to communicate with each other.  One will be an Android platform, so I will be using Java.  The other node will be a RaspberryPi running Debian Linux.  While I COULD use Java on this end as well and maybe just use RPC, what I would LIKE to do is develop my own little implementation-agnostic TCP/IP "protocol"  for the two to communicate, and let the each implement it however works best.  What I mean by "protocol" is I want a standard set of messages to be passed back and forth, along with some values with each.  E.g.:

```
"Protocol" Definition:
MESSAGE TYPE A (Float arg, Int arg)
MESSAGE TYPE B (Int arg)
MESSAGE TYPE C (Int arg, String arg, Int arg)
```

An example "conversation":

```
Node 1                              Node 2
              A(5.4, 4)    --->
              B(6)         --->
        <---- C(3, 'Hello', 0xFF)
              B(5)         --->
        <---- A(43.0, 16)
```

So my questions are:

(1) Does the above even make sense?  Do I need to clarify my intent?  Provide more info?  This is my first forray into networked communication between two running programs, so I may be way off-base in what I'm asking for.  If I'm approaching this the wrong way, I'd be happy for better recommendations.

(2) How would I go about this?  Do I just stuff one long string into a TCP packet?  Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to fill a buffer with the data you want and then learn how to open and send data through a TCP socket. The kernel will handle how to arrange the payload and how to control the TCP stream. On the server end, you must learn how to listen on a TCP socket and read incoming data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  What type of data goes in the buffers?  A stream of characters?  Bytes?

Comment: The buffer is an array of bytes. You can write whatever you want, but you have to pay attention to network/host order conversion when you want to write multi-byte entities like integers.

Answer (score 1):

Socket Programming is the word you should be searching for.